# JavaScript is not executed in Cordova with WebStorm

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, webstorm, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new into this hybrid development approach. I have a Cordova project. In my index.html, I have a button:

```
<div><button id ="resourceRequestBTN" style="float:left; margin-top:10px;">Resource Request</button> </div>
```

and I have also defined the JavaScript files in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

In the `index.js` (the main one: `ProjectRoot/www/js/`) I have added event listener for that button:

```
document.getElementById("resourceRequestBTN").addEventListener("click", resourceRequestGetBalance, false);
console.log("response ");
function resourceRequestGetBalance(){
    console.log("response ");
    try{
        var request = new WLResourceRequest('/adapters/account/balance', WLResourceRequest.GET);
        request.send().then(
            function(response) {
                var response = JSON.stringify(response);
                console.log("response " + response);
                alert(response);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("error " + error);
            }
        ).fail(function(){
            console.log("WLResourceRequest failure");
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log("exception:"+ err);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the button appears, but when I click on it, nothing happens. Even the logs do not appear. Maybe the code is not executed at all, but why?

The iOS emulator gives me the path to the log file:

```
logPath: /.../Projects/Hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

But the log file does not exist...

Comment: If you wait about 30 seconds + , do you see anything?

Comment: No, I dont see anything